# How to get the filename and path from an upload control in xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a document that the user attaches a file to an upload control called licenseKey. In a SSJS I need to retrieve the content of that file and process it. I know that it is a ASCII text file and I know the general format. I would like to create var inStream:NotesStream for the content of the attachment, but I can't see how to do this in SSJS.
I have tried using getComponent("licenseKey") but don't see what might be next. 
This code would actually be run by the user that attaches the file, so the local File Path and File Name would be valid if I could get them from the upLoad Control.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the filename from the XPages FileUpload Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803158/how-do-you-get-the-filename-from-the-xpages-fileupload-control)

Answer (score 2):

Julian Buss did a nice explanation
[here](http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_a_file_upload_and_download_controls). Quote:

> **How to process an uploaded file**
>
> Place code like this in the beforeRenderResponse event of an XPage to
>   get a handle to a just-uploaded file:
>
> ```
> var con = facesContext.getExternalContext(); 
> var request:com.sun.faces.context.MyHttpServletRequestWrapper = con.getRequest(); 
> var map:java.util.Map = request.getParameterMap(); 
> var fileDataName = "file"; //name of the POST request parameter that contains the file 
> var fileData:com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile = map.get( fileDataName ); 
> var tempFile:java.io.File = fileData.getServerFile();
> ```
>
> The file is in the "xspupload" directory on the Domino Server and has
>   some crypting filename. You can get the original filename with
>   fileData.getClientFileName().
>
> For example, you can attach the file to some Notes document with code
>   like this:
>
> ```
> var correctedFile = new java.io.File( tempFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + java.io.File.separator +
> ```
>
> fileData.getClientFileName() ); 
>       var success = tempFile.renameTo(correctedFile); //rtFiles is a rich text item on a notesdocument of your chosing
>   rtFiles.embedObject(lotus.domino.local.EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT,
>   "", correctedFile.getAbsolutePath(), null); 
>       correctedFile.renameTo(tempFile);
>
> This snippet renames the temporary file to the orginal filename,
>   attaches it to a RichText item and renames it back to the cryptic name
>   (so that it will be deleted by Domino after processing).

Comment: beforerenderresponse:
try{
dBar.info("in try")
var con = facesContext.getExternalContext(); 
var request:com.sun.faces.context.MyHttpServletRequestWrapper = con.getRequest(); 
var map:java.util.Map = request.getParameterMap(); 
var fileDataName = "file"; //name of the POST request parameter that contains the file 
var fileData:com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile = map.get( fileDataName ); 
dBar.info(fileData,"Got fileData");
var tempFile:java.io.File = fileData.getServerFile();
dBar.info(tempFile, "got tempFile")
viewScope.put("vsLicenseFile",tempFile);

}catch(e){
 dBar.info("Nothing or error");
}

Comment: but it never gets past the message Got fileData. Which is what I would expect until I enter the value in the upload. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think I'm going about this the wrong way. Actually I only need the upload control to get the filename and path, I really don't need the file attached to the document.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in beforerenderResponse:

```
var fileData:com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getParameterMap().get(getClientId('fileUpload1'));

if (fileData != null) {    
    var tempFile:java.io.File = fileData.getServerFile();
...
```